# Which port is which in Ancient Art of War at Sea?

Tags: ancient-art-of-war-at-sea

There are two types of ports in Ancient Art of War at Sea, "repair" and "supply". The manual doesn't seem to tell you which is which, though.

[image: Port Island]

There's an [FAQ floating around](http://www.virtualapple.org/docs/document-18.html) that says a repair port "looks like a fort", and the supply port "looks like a town". Those descriptions are still kind of confusing, though. One port has a barn and people walking around, which makes me think "town", but also what could be towers at the corners, which suggests "fort".

Where do I park my ships to get them fixed up? The enemy's closing in, and I haven't got time to put them in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually mentioned in the manual, but it's in a strange -- almost hidden -- place, at the bottom of page 21 of Book I, in the description of the "Symbols" pane of the Map Generator.

It says the first port [image: Five buildings, one long, one L-shaped] is for repairs.

The other, with the people walking around, [image: Round objects at three corners, barn at fourth] is your supply port.